# Cannot Access with an Instance Reference

Tags: c#, system.diagnostics

While I can do this:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"C:\MyFolder\MyProgram.cmd");
```

I can't do this:

```
var process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
process.Start(@"C:\MyFolder\MyProgram.cmd");
```

Error: Member 'System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(string)' cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead.

What is the reason behind this? Can anyone please explain?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e8zac0ca(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it's a static method.  You can't use it off an instance of `Process`:

```
public static Process Start(string fileName)
```

Use the empty [Start() method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e8zac0ca(v=vs.110).aspx), that is designed to work off an instance:

> Starts (or reuses) the process resource that is specified by the StartInfo property of this Process component and associates it with the component.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Jonesopolis.

Answer (score 6):

All the parametered overloads of [`Process.Start`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process_methods(v=vs.110).aspx) are static. If you want to use the second syntax then you have to set instance state first which is just the "filename" property of `StartInfo`:

```
var proc = new Process();
proc.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\MyFolder\MyProgram.cmd";
proc.Start();
```

Note that this should be equivalent to `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"C:\MyFolder\MyProgram.cmd");` because as the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53ezey2s(v=vs.110).aspx) says: "The overload is an alternative to the explicit steps of creating a new Process instance, setting the FileName member of the StartInfo property, and calling Start for the Process instance."

Comment: Thanks Quantic. This really helps.

Answer (score 2):

That's because [`System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(string)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e8zac0ca(v=vs.110).aspx) is a static method.

You can't invoke static members of a class from an instance of that type.

It would be the same as invoking a private static method in an instance method via `this.MyStaticMethod()`.

Edit: You might want to set the [`StartInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.startinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) of the Process then invoke the [`Start`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e8zac0ca(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

Comment: Thanks Marius. As a beginner, everything feels like dynamic then here comes the static methods.